# How to get back my files folder committed to local repo and not pushed to my feature branch in bitbucket

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

Trying to get back my `files` committed to local repo and not pushed to my feature branch in bitbucket

Steps

1. Remote Master `files` folder is deleted and commit made on remote master by other users
2. Created a Feature branch from remote master and locally added and modified some of the files in `files` folder and made a commit locally `(I have not yet pushed my changes to bitbucket)`
3. Did a git pull from remote master on my local feature branch and I see no files in my `Files` folder with conflict saying files deleted

How to recover my `files` folder which I have made a commit locally and since the `files` folder is deleted in master remote and git pull on local has led to conflicts and unable recover the `files`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exit the merge:

`git merge --abort`

This should restore the files as long as no other commits were made which deleted `files`.

If there were, use `git log` to find the hash of the commit where the `files` folder is and then run

`git checkout <commit hash>`

This will allow you to view those files without changing the history.

If you wish to reset the branch to that commit then use

`git reset --hard <commit hash>`

WARNING: this will locally erase anything committed after *commit hash*